# Concatenar SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT UPPER(admatribuido)        AS [admAtribuido], 
       Count(admatribuido) AS [quantidade_admAtribuido] 
FROM   ##tmp 
WHERE  Month(dataabertura) = Month(Getdate()) 
       AND Year(dataabertura) = Year(Getdate())
AND admAtribuido <> 'null'
GROUP  BY admatribuido
```

Que me traz o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de concatenar um traço " - " e a quantidade_admAtribuido no admAtribuido, por exemplo:

```
admAtribuido              |   quantidade_admAtribuido               
ANA PAULA SOARES - 100    |   100
```

Comment: Caso esteja usando Sql Server 2016 existe o tsql `Contat`, será algo parecido com: `SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(admatribuido), '-' ,Count(admatribuido))...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT concat( UPPER(admatribuido), ' - ',cast([quantidade_admAtribuido] as varchar(100)))        AS [admAtribuido], 
   Count(admatribuido) AS [quantidade_admAtribuido]
```

Use a função concat como no exemplo acima

Answer (score 3):

Usa o operador de concatenação padrão do MSSQL, o "+":

1 - Com os 2 campos:

```
SELECT (UPPER(admatribuido) + ' - ' + Count(admatribuido)) AS [admAtribuido], 
       Count(admatribuido) AS [quantidade_admAtribuido] 
FROM   ##tmp 
WHERE  Month(dataabertura) = Month(Getdate()) 
       AND Year(dataabertura) = Year(Getdate())
AND admAtribuido <> 'null'
GROUP  BY admatribuido
```

2 - Com 1 campo:

```
SELECT (UPPER(admatribuido) + ' - ' + Count(admatribuido)) AS [admAtribuido]
FROM   ##tmp 
WHERE  Month(dataabertura) = Month(Getdate()) 
       AND Year(dataabertura) = Year(Getdate())
AND admAtribuido <> 'null'
GROUP  BY admatribuido
```

Essa solução se aplica pra essas aplicações abaixo:

SQL Server (a partir de 2008)
Banco de Dados SQL do Microsoft Azure
Azure SQL Data Warehouse 
Parallel Data Warehouse